# Logrotate on "not always on" system

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, logrotate

I have several Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 systems, whose have no defined operating hours, for example desktop, laptop or VMs runt on demand. What are the right ways and tools to automatically rotate logs on them, f.e. starting missed logrotate runs immediately on startup?

Answer (score 3):

**Do Nothing Special. Ubuntu is already set up for this.**

Ubuntu includes *[anacron](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/anacron.8.html)*, which cleverly keeps track of cron jobs and triggers missed jobs when the system next becomes available.

Anacron already keeps track of daily jobs in /etc/cron.daily, including logrotate.

Example: If an Ubuntu VM is shut down on Tuesday and started again on Friday, then anacron will run one set of daily cron jobs a few minutes after the VM has completed booting on Friday. The time of day on Friday doesn't matter -- anacron will determine that over 24 hours have elapsed since the last daily job.

Comment: Exactly. `anacron` keeps track of when the daily/weekly/etc. jobs have run last time in the files below `/var/spool/anacron/` (in case someone is curious).

Answer (score 1):

Simply make a logrotate call hourly (by put the config in to `/etc/cron.hourly/`) and configure the rotation as per you wish for each configuration, for example adding the `weekly` option in the logrotate config. 
Like this the logrotate job start every our, but will act on the logs file only once a week.

Logrotate [Documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix is to add /etc/cron.daily/logrotate script to /etc/rc.local script. So /etc/cron.daily/logrotate runs every boot, rotates logs if were not rotated recently and rotates nothing if logs were always rotated recently. Then, the regular /etc/cron.*/ jobs are in effect if system is online long enough. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS.